# artificial intelligence (neural networks) - actual output never gets near the correct output

Tags: java, neural-network, artificial-intelligence

I am working on a program which should act like a XOR-operator.

In order to adjust the weights I use backprop.

I have also included deep learning (which works nearly as it should, the same struggle here) but this shouldn't be from importance. (When there is a if-clause like

```
if(hiddenNeurons.size() > 1)
{
 .....
}
```

than there is just code in this if which is from importance when using multiple hidden neurons. (Which is in this question not the case))

The struggle: The output is no matter what the input is, nearly always the same (around 0.5).

The weights and biases get adjusted.

Here is the code (there is more, but the other code isn't from importance):

```
public void learnFromData(int iterations) //this method learns from the ArrayList 'inputs' and 'outputs'
{
            if(inputs.size() == outputs.size())
            {
                //Collections.shuffle(inputs);  
                for(int j = 0;j<iterations;j++)
                {
                for(int i = 0;i<inputs.size();i++)
                {

                    double actualOutput = computeOutput(inputs.get(i))[0];
                    double expectedOutput = outputs.get(i)[0];


                    //System.out.println(String.format("Input: %.3f /\\ Ouput: %.4f Expected: %.4f",inputs.get(i)[0], actualOutput, expectedOutput));
                    double error = 0;
                    if (actualOutput > expectedOutput) {
                        error = actualOutput - expectedOutput;
                    } else {
                        error = expectedOutput - actualOutput;
                    }
                    if(i == 0){
                    System.out.println(String.format("Error: %.10f", error));}
                    learn(outputs.get(i));
                }
            }
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("\nERROR: the number of inputs and outputs have to match!\n");
        }
    }
public double[] computeOutput(double[] inputValues)
   {

    for(int i = 0;i<inputValues.length;i++) //giving the inputNeurons a value
    {
        inputNeurons[i] = inputValues[i];
    }
    for(int i = 0;i<hiddenNeurons.get(0).length;i++) 
    {
        hSums.get(0)[i] = 0.0;
    }
    for(int i = 0;i<aOutputNeurons.length;i++)
    {
        hoSums[i] = 0.0;
    }
    for(int i = 0;i<inputNeurons.length;i++) //calculating the sums of the hidden neurons (Input-function)
    {
        for(int b = 0;b<hiddenNeurons.get(0).length;b++)
        {
            hSums.get(0)[b] += inputNeurons[i] * ihWeights[i][b];
        }
    }
    for(int i = 0;i<hiddenNeurons.get(0).length;i++) //Each bias-value has to be added to its associated sum 
    {
       hSums.get(0)[i] += hBiases.get(0)[i];
    }


    for(int i = 0;i<hiddenNeurons.get(0).length;i++)
    {
        hiddenNeurons.get(0)[i] = Helper.sig(hSums.get(0)[i]); //output-function = sigmoid
    }

    //calculating the hSums
    if(hiddenNeurons.size()>1)
    {
        for (int layer = 0;layer<hiddenNeurons.size()-1;layer++) 
        {   
            //calculating the sums of the layer
            for(int neuron_nextLayer = 0; neuron_nextLayer < hiddenNeurons.get(layer+1).length;neuron_nextLayer++)
            {
                hSums.get(layer+1)[neuron_nextLayer] = 0;
                for(int neuron_actualLayer = 0;neuron_actualLayer < hiddenNeurons.get(layer).length;neuron_actualLayer++)
                {
                    hSums.get(layer+1)[neuron_nextLayer] += hiddenNeurons.get(layer)[neuron_actualLayer] * hhWeights.get(layer)[neuron_actualLayer][neuron_nextLayer];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    // calculating the sums of the output neurons (Input-function)
    int lastHiddenLayer = hiddenNeurons.size()-1;
    for(int i = 0;i<aOutputNeurons.length;i++) 
    {
        hoSums[i] = 0;
        for(int b = 0;b<hiddenNeurons.get(lastHiddenLayer).length;b++)
        {
            hoSums[i] += hiddenNeurons.get(lastHiddenLayer)[b] * hoWeights[b][i];
        }
        hoSums[i] += hoBiases[i];
        aOutputNeurons[i] = Helper.sig(hoSums[i]);
    }
    //weightToString();
    return aOutputNeurons;
   }
   public void learn(double[] cValues) //correctValues
   {
    // calculating the output-gradients 
    for(int i = 0;i<aOutputNeurons.length;i++)
    {
        oGradients[i] = (cValues[i]-aOutputNeurons[i])*Helper.invSig(aOutputNeurons[i]);
    }

    //calculating the hidden-gradients
    double sum; //sum of all multiplications between gradients of the output layer and the weights between the hidden neuron and each output neuron.
    int lastHiddenLayer = hiddenNeurons.size()-1;
    for(int i = 0;i<hiddenNeurons.get(lastHiddenLayer).length;i++)
    {
        sum = 0;
        for(int b = 0;b<aOutputNeurons.length;b++)
        {
            sum += oGradients[b] * hoWeights[i][b];
        }
        hGradients.get(lastHiddenLayer)[i] = Helper.invSig(hiddenNeurons.get(lastHiddenLayer)[i]) * sum;
    }

    if(hiddenNeurons.size() > 1)
    {
        for(int layer = lastHiddenLayer;layer > 0;layer--)
        {

            for(int neuron_actualHiddenLayer = 0; neuron_actualHiddenLayer < hiddenNeurons.get(layer-1).length;neuron_actualHiddenLayer++) // neuron_actualHiddenLayer is more in the direction of the input neurons and neuron_nextHiddenLayer more in the direction of the output neurons
            {
                sum = 0;

                for(int neuron_nextHiddenLayer = 0;neuron_nextHiddenLayer < hiddenNeurons.get(layer).length;neuron_nextHiddenLayer++)
                {
                    sum += hGradients.get(layer)[neuron_nextHiddenLayer] * hhWeights.get(layer-1)[neuron_actualHiddenLayer][neuron_nextHiddenLayer];
                }  
                hGradients.get(layer-1)[neuron_actualHiddenLayer] = Helper.invSig(hiddenNeurons.get(layer-1)[neuron_actualHiddenLayer]) * sum;
            }
        }
    }


    //calculating weight- and biasdeltas of input- to hidden neurons
    for(int i = 0;i<inputNeurons.length;i++)
    {
        for(int b = 0;b<hiddenNeurons.get(0).length;b++)
        {
            ihPrevWeightsDeltas[i][b] = eta * hGradients.get(0)[b] * inputNeurons[i];
            ihWeights[i][b] += ihPrevWeightsDeltas[i][b];
        }
    }
    // calculating weight- and biasdeltas of hidden- to hidden neurons
    if(hiddenNeurons.size() > 1)
    {
        for(int layer = 0;layer < hiddenNeurons.size()-1;layer++)
        {
            for(int neuron_actualHiddenLayer = 0; neuron_actualHiddenLayer < hiddenNeurons.get(layer).length;neuron_actualHiddenLayer++) // neuron_actualHiddenLayer is more in the direction of the input neurons and neuron_nextHiddenLayer more in the direction of the output neurons
            {
                for(int neuron_nextHiddenLayer = 0;neuron_nextHiddenLayer < hiddenNeurons.get(layer+1).length;neuron_nextHiddenLayer++)
                {
                    hhPrevWeightDeltas.get(layer)[neuron_actualHiddenLayer][neuron_nextHiddenLayer] = eta * hGradients.get(layer+1)[neuron_nextHiddenLayer] * hiddenNeurons.get(layer)[neuron_actualHiddenLayer];
                    hhWeights.get(layer)[neuron_actualHiddenLayer][neuron_nextHiddenLayer] += hhPrevWeightDeltas.get(layer)[neuron_actualHiddenLayer][neuron_nextHiddenLayer];
                    hhPrevBiasDeltas.get(layer)[neuron_actualHiddenLayer] = eta*hGradients.get(layer)[neuron_actualHiddenLayer];
                    hBiases.get(layer)[neuron_actualHiddenLayer] += hhPrevBiasDeltas.get(layer)[neuron_actualHiddenLayer];
                }  
            }
        }
    }
    for(int i = 0;i<hiddenNeurons.get(0).length;i++)
    {
        ihPrevBiasDeltas[i] = eta*hGradients.get(0)[i];
        hBiases.get(0)[i] += ihPrevBiasDeltas[i];
    }
    for(int i = 0;i<aOutputNeurons.length;i++)
    {
        hoPrevBiasDeltas[i] = eta*oGradients[i];
        hoBiases[i] += hoPrevBiasDeltas[i];
    }
    for(int i = 0;i<hiddenNeurons.get(0).length;i++)
    {
        for(int b = 0;b<aOutputNeurons.length;b++)
        {
            hoPrevWeightsDeltas[i][b] = eta * oGradients[b] * hiddenNeurons.get(lastHiddenLayer)[i];
            hoWeights[i][b] += hoPrevWeightsDeltas[i][b];
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Could you please turn this into a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and maybe make it more readable? It's a *lot* of code, especially since you say that there is code which isn't relevant to the matter at hand.

Comment: Yeah I know, I thought that somebody would say that.
But how could I make the code more readable? Do you mean just less code where you have a better overview (which isn't possible in this case) or should I put in the whole code I have in order to "provide all parts needed to reproduce the problem"  (Which is A LOT)?

Comment: `But how could I make the code more readable?` That is your problem, we already have one, which is understanding and answering the question :) However, you say that there are bits that are irrelevant, maybe start with removing those, improve formatting and if you are feeling generous, after editing it into the question, upload the result, together with any additional boilerplate code needed to actually run it, somewhere (e.g. Github)? Read the definition of a MCVE [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: sounds good, thank you, I will think about doing it. Especially because I saw in the answer below that this question/the amount of code isn't the best in order to allow a good overview.

Answer (score 1):

Because it is your own code, please try to do same network using some matured project like the Neuroph library and compare the results, it should help you to narrow the problem.

also remember that XOR function is a non-linear classification problem, you need at least 2 layers (1 input and 1 hidden) with non-linear activation function. It just because linear classifier can't be adjusted to do non-linear classification, you need to have non-linear classifier.

Comment: How did you recognize that my network consists only of 1 layer? (Maybe I formulated something wrong in the question).

Because I actually have 1 input- , 1 hidden- and 1 output layer.

Comment: Are you sure about your code? try with Neuroph library, try to do the same. It is matured project and such test will tell you if your code is ok, because I can't test your code if it is correct or not, simply because it is very sophisticated and I don't have time.

Comment: I pretty sure that I have min. 3 layers.

I have .csv-Files where I save all the weights and biases between the different layers.

It may be good to put in the constructor that everybody can see that there really are 3 layers.

Comment: No library, I created that all on my own

Comment: Do you have unit tests for your code? Are you sure it is working as expected? Please do same network using Neuroph project and compare your results, it should help you to narrow the problem.

Comment: Ok yes, I already tried the GUI of Neuroph before starting my project in order to gain some oversight over ANNs. Thank you!